# cpio fails to extract files

Tags: archive, cpio

In the following sequence of commands, why does `cpio` fails to extract the files previously archived?

```
/home/pkara/Desktop/temp
$ ls
eBooks  myfile.tar
/home/pkara/Desktop/temp
$ find . -depth -print | cpio -ov > backup.cpio
./backup.cpio
./myfile.tar
./eBooks/logstash_atlantis/03_output.conf
./eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_01_filter_paloalto.conf
./eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_02_filter_squid.conf
./eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_99_metrics_filter.conf
./eBooks/logstash_atlantis/01_input.conf
./eBooks/logstash_atlantis
./eBooks/Container-Networking-Docker-Kubernetes.pdf
./eBooks/lpic-1_2013.pdf
./eBooks/linux-bible-by-christopher-negus.pdf
./eBooks/PythonNotesForProfessionals.pdf
./eBooks/lpic1-notes
./eBooks
.
129731 blocks
/home/pkara/Desktop/temp
$ mkdir -p foo
/home/pkara/Desktop/temp
$ mv backup.cpio foo && cd $_
/home/pkara/Desktop/temp/foo
$ cpio -iv < backup.cpio 
cpio: backup.cpio not created: newer or same age version exists
backup.cpio
myfile.tar
cpio: eBooks/logstash_atlantis/03_output.conf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/logstash_atlantis/03_output.conf
cpio: eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_01_filter_paloalto.conf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_01_filter_paloalto.conf
cpio: eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_02_filter_squid.conf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_02_filter_squid.conf
cpio: eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_99_metrics_filter.conf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/logstash_atlantis/02_99_metrics_filter.conf
cpio: eBooks/logstash_atlantis/01_input.conf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/logstash_atlantis/01_input.conf
cpio: eBooks/logstash_atlantis: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
eBooks/logstash_atlantis
cpio: eBooks/Container-Networking-Docker-Kubernetes.pdf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/Container-Networking-Docker-Kubernetes.pdf
cpio: eBooks/lpic-1_2013.pdf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/lpic-1_2013.pdf
cpio: eBooks/linux-bible-by-christopher-negus.pdf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/linux-bible-by-christopher-negus.pdf
cpio: eBooks/PythonNotesForProfessionals.pdf: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/PythonNotesForProfessionals.pdf
cpio: eBooks/lpic1-notes: Cannot open: No such file or directory
eBooks/lpic1-notes
eBooks
.
129731 blocks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you use the `-depth` option in `find`. This tells `find` to process the directory contents before the directory itself.

As you can see in the output of `find . -depth -print | cpio -ov > backup.cpio`:

- `./eBooks/logstash_atlantis/03_output.conf` is processed before the directory `./eBooks/logstash_atlantis`
- `./eBooks/Container-Networking-Docker-Kubernetes.pdf` is processed before `./eBooks`.
- ...

When you try to extract the archive it fails for all files in subdirectories, because the directories don't exist yet ("Cannot open: No such file or directory").

It also fails for `./backup.cpio`, because it already exists in this directory.

**Solution:** Don't use the `-depth` option of `find` in combination with `cpio`.

Comment: This works and I have accepted your answer, however if for example if I name my file `archive.cpio`, during extraction I get: `cpio: archive.cpio not created: newer or same age version exists`

Comment: @pkaramol Your archive exists in the directory _and_ in the archive itself, because it was created in the same directory as the files. You can (1) exclude the archive from `find` with `find . ! -name *.cpio -print | cpio -ov  > archive.cpio` or (2) create the archive in a different directory: `find . -print | cpio -ov  > /tmp/archive.cpio`